# Use dc.seriesChart as a child chart to dc.compositeChart

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I need to draw a complex chart with two Y axes and several series bounded to each Y axis. Besides, X values for each series are different. So I tried to create two seriesCharts and to compose them by one compositeChart. And i had an exception that seemed to be impossible to use seriesChart as a child chart.  Is it true? Is there another solution? Thanks.

I have data structure like that:

{id1 = 0    id2 = 0 value = 5,95796 date = 5.24.15 0:00}

0 | 0 | 5,83062 | 5.24.15 0:01

5 | 0 | 24757   | 5.24.15 4:21

5 | 0 | 24638 | 5.24.15 4:22

9 | 1 | 391,6 | 5.24.15 9:00

9 | 1 | 391,6 | 5.24.15 9:31

First id is the number of the series, second id (0 or 1) tells what Y axis should be used. 'Value' is Y value, date is X. Dataset is very large and up to 40000 records can be displayed for each series. I'm new with dc.js and have really broken my neck figuring out how to manage it. Maybe i'm going the wrong way. I really appreciate any advice!

Comment: Not sure - can you put together an example? Also, this is another dc.js question that seems reasonable but got mysteriously down voted with no reason given. If down voters could post a note as to why, that would be helpful!

Comment: Looks like there is an issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/854

Comment: Since series is just a shortcut for composing a bunch of the same chart, I'd try composing them yourself, in a loop. This does mean splitting your groups into smaller groups.